# Matrix algebra over finite field

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose $A$ and $B$ are two matrices having their minimal polynomial P($\lambda$)=$a_N.\lambda^N$+$a_{N-1}.\lambda^{N-1}$...+$a_1$ ($a_N=1$). 
In addition, suppose P($\lambda$)=$g_j(\lambda)$.$g_k(\lambda)$...$g_l(\lambda)$ (Product of irreducible polynomials).

For all vector $v$ such that $g_j(A)v$=**0** then there exists another vector $u$ for which $g_j(B)u$=**0**. Here **0** denotes the null vector.

Question is: Are A and B Similar?

Answer (score 1):

The matrices \begin{bmatrix}1 &  & \\  & 1 & \\  &  & 0 \end{bmatrix} and\begin{bmatrix}1 &  & \\ & 0 & \\ &  & 0\end{bmatrix} have X(X-1) as minimal polynomial but are not similar since they don't have the same rank.

Comment: You are right. I know this. But if you look the question very carefully, I have put an additional condition with the condition same minimal polynomial of A and B. Does that condition enough to infer A and B similar.